# Dynamically creating JavaScript handler

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make the creation of these event handlers in [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/iangilman/pen/BpwBJe) dynamic.

There are two viewers, and each has a handler.  What if I want 4 viewers?  I have to repeat the code over and over.

So instead of doing this:

```
var viewer1Leading = false;
var viewer2Leading = false;

var viewer1Handler = function() {
  if (viewer2Leading) {
    return;
  }

  viewer1Leading = true;
  viewer2.viewport.zoomTo(viewer1.viewport.getZoom());
  viewer2.viewport.panTo(viewer1.viewport.getCenter());
  viewer1Leading = false;
};

var viewer2Handler = function() {
  if (viewer1Leading) {
    return;
  }

  viewer2Leading = true;
  viewer1.viewport.zoomTo(viewer2.viewport.getZoom());
  viewer1.viewport.panTo(viewer2.viewport.getCenter());
  viewer2Leading = false;
};

viewer1.addHandler('zoom', viewer1Handler);
viewer2.addHandler('zoom', viewer2Handler);
viewer1.addHandler('pan', viewer1Handler);
viewer2.addHandler('pan', viewer2Handler);
```

I want to be able to sort of do that:

```
// Our array of viewers
let objArray = [createViewerObj(viewer1), createViewerObj(viewer2)];

// We need a viewer handler for each viewer
let viewerHandler = function (activeViewer, objArray) {

  let theOthers = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
    if (activeViewer.id !== objArray[i].id) {
      theOthers.push(objArray[i]);
    }
  }
  // OK, now I have an array of everything but the "active" viewer.

  for (let i = 0; i < theOthers.length; i++) {
    // If any other viewer is leading, return.
    if (theOthers[i].isLeading) {
      return;
    }
  }

  activeViewer.isLeading = true; // Turn on.
  objArray.forEach(function (obj) {
    // Set viewport for all viewers
    obj.viewer.viewport.zoomTo(activeViewer.viewport.getZoom());
    obj.viewer.viewport.panTo(activeViewer.viewport.getCenter());
  });
  activeViewer.isLeading = false; // Turn off.
};

// Add handlers
objArray.forEach(function (obj) {
  // When Viewer i is zooming we want Viewer i to lead
  obj.viewer.addHandler('zoom', viewerHandler(obj.viewer, objArray));
  // When Viewer i is panning we want Viewer i to lead
  obj.viewer.addHandler('pan', viewerHandler(obj.viewer, objArray));
});

// Create obj with props
function createViewerObj(viewer) {
  return {
    id: viewer.id,
    isLeading: false,
    viewer: viewer
  }
}
```

But it's not working - the viewers are no longer synchronized.

Also I wanted to make the code *less* clunky, but now it's more clunky.

Any ideas?

Modified CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/aquacapri/pen/LwQYWr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var globalConfig = {
    Image: {
        xmlns: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/deepzoom/2008",
        Url: "//openseadragon.github.io/example-images/duomo/duomo_files/",
        Format: "jpg",
        Overlap: "2",
        TileSize: "256",
        Size: {
            Width: "13920",
            Height: "10200"
        }
    }
};

function createSyncedViews(imageSrc, ids) {
    var syncedViews = []
    var activeViewer = null;  //magic init

    ids.forEach(function (id) {
        var currentViewer = OpenSeadragon({
            id: id,
            prefixUrl: imageSrc,
            tileSources: globalConfig
        })

        currentViewer.addHandler('pan', handler);
        currentViewer.addHandler('zoom', handler);

        function handler() {

            console.log(id, activeViewer);

            //this magic is required to skip few initial events triggering while image is loading or whatever
            //without it, this funky DraagonView will end up in stackoverlow
            if (activeViewer == null)activeViewer = id;
            if (activeViewer != id)return;
            //end magic

            syncedViews.forEach(function (view) {
                if (view.id == id) {
                    return
                }
                view.viewport.zoomTo(currentViewer.viewport.getZoom());
                view.viewport.panTo(currentViewer.viewport.getCenter());

            })
            //magic support
            activeViewer = null;

        }

        syncedViews.push(currentViewer)
    })


}

createSyncedViews("//openseadragon.github.io/openseadragon/images/", ['viewer1', 'viewer2','viewer3'])
```

try [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JgpoyQ)

Comment: Awesome solution.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

this is my way

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Synchronized Viewers</title>
  <style>
    .seadragon-viewer {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 45%;
      height: 600px;
    }
  </style>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//openseadragon.github.io/openseadragon/openseadragon.min.js"></script>



  <script>
    // Define our image
    var duomo = {
      Image: {
        xmlns: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/deepzoom/2008",
        Url: "//openseadragon.github.io/example-images/duomo/duomo_files/",
        Format: "jpg",
        Overlap: "2",
        TileSize: "256",
        Size: {
          Width: "13920",
          Height: "10200"
        }
      }
    };

    // Create osd viewer
    function createViewer(id, tileSources) {
      return OpenSeadragon({
        id: id,
        prefixUrl: "//openseadragon.github.io/openseadragon/images/",
        tileSources: tileSources
      });
    }

    // Create obj with props
    function createViewerObj(viewer) {
      return {
        id: viewer.id,
        isLeading: false,
        viewer: viewer
      }
    }

    // Now create the viewers

$(function(){

  function dynamic_createView(arrViews){

    var htmlContent="";

    for (var i = 0; i < arrViews.length; i++) {
      htmlContent+='<div id="'+arrViews[i]+'" class="seadragon-viewer"></div>';
    }


    $("#mainView")[0].innerHTML=htmlContent;


    for (var i = 0; i < arrViews.length; i++) {
      window[arrViews[i]]= createViewer(arrViews[i],duomo);
    }    

    var objArray= [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arrViews.length; i++) {
      objArray[i]=createViewerObj(window[arrViews[i]]);
    }



    // We need a viewer handler for each viewer
    var viewerHandler = function (activeViewer, objArray) {

      var theOthers = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
        if (activeViewer.id !== objArray[i].id) {
          theOthers.push(objArray[i]);
        }
      }
      // OK, now I have an array of everything but the "active" viewer.

      for (var i = 0; i < theOthers.length; i++) {
        // If any other viewer is leading, return.
        if (theOthers[i].isLeading) {
          return;
        }
      }

      activeViewer.isLeading = true; // Turn on.
      objArray.forEach(function (obj) {
        // Set viewport for all viewers
        obj.viewer.viewport.zoomTo(activeViewer.viewport.getZoom());
        obj.viewer.viewport.panTo(activeViewer.viewport.getCenter());
      });
      activeViewer.isLeading = false; // Turn off.
    };

    // Add handlers
    objArray.forEach(function (obj) {
      // When Viewer i is zooming we want Viewer i to lead
      obj.viewer.addHandler('zoom', viewerHandler(obj.viewer, objArray));
      // When Viewer i is panning we want Viewer i to lead
      obj.viewer.addHandler('pan', viewerHandler(obj.viewer, objArray));
    });
  }


dynamic_createView(["viewer1","viewer2","viewer3"]);

});

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mainView"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok, not bad.  But I tried it in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera, and it doesn't work.  Thanks anyway.